# Access date picker value not recognized in SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am trying to use two date pickers combined with a button in an Access form to filter the query.
The two date pickers simply define the range of the dates and the button is to execute the query that's written in SQL. After I hit the button, however, Access still needs me to manually put in the parameter value by showing the "Enter Parameter Value" window.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my design or my code?

```
SELECT Tsheets_Start_Fm_20200829.fname, Tsheets_Start_Fm_20200829.lname, Tsheets_Start_Fm_20200829.local_date, Tsheets_Start_Fm_20200829.jobcode_1, Tsheets_Start_Fm_20200829.jobcode_2, Tsheets_Start_Fm_20200829.billable
FROM Tsheets_Start_Fm_20200829
WHERE (((Tsheets_Start_Fm_20200829.local_date) Between [Forms]![Weekly_Interface]![start_date] And [Forms]![Weekly_Interface]![end_date]));
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the code behind that button?

Comment: The on-click event is simply execute the SQL query that's shown above. I didn't write a vb code for that. I just select "miscellaneous", "run query" when creating the button.

Comment: So using embedded macro? Are you actually using OpenQuery command? I tested this and works. Cannot replicate issue.